# jquery click event for open same elements in different clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 blocks that have button #add-note with click event and this button should open block with .add-note class. If I click on any of these buttons it opens me 2 divs but I need that button opens 1 div that appera to these div.

```
$('#add-note').click(function() {
    $('.add-note').toggle('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});

<ul class="list-unstyled alerts-list contracts-alert-list">
                        <li>
                            <div class="alert-list-left">
                                <div class="alert-time  contracts-alert">
                                    <p>10:31 AM</p>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="alert-title">Alert 1</span>

                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <a href=""><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="alert-list-left">
                                <div class="alert-time  contracts-alert">
                                    <p>10:31 AM</p>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="alert-title">Alert 1</span>

                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <a href=""><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="alert-list-left">
                                <div class="alert-time  contracts-alert">
                                    <p>10:31 AM</p>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="alert-title">Alert 1</span>

                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <a href=""><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="add-note add-note">
                            <form action="some-action" class="add-note-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn form-submit-btn" id="submit-new-note-2">Add Note</button>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <button type="button" class="btn add-alert-btn" id="add-note"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Note Here</button>


<ul class="list-unstyled alerts-list contracts-alert-list">
                        <li>
                            <div class="alert-list-left">
                                <div class="alert-time  contracts-alert">
                                    <p>10:31 AM</p>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="alert-title">Alert 1</span>

                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <a href=""><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="alert-list-left">
                                <div class="alert-time  contracts-alert">
                                    <p>10:31 AM</p>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="alert-title">Alert 1</span>

                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <a href=""><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="alert-list-left">
                                <div class="alert-time  contracts-alert">
                                    <p>10:31 AM</p>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="alert-title">Alert 1</span>

                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <a href=""><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="add-note add-note">
                            <form action="some-action" class="add-note-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn form-submit-btn" id="submit-new-note-2">Add Note</button>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <button type="button" class="btn add-alert-btn" id="add-note"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Note Here</button>
```

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: If you include your jQuery code maybe someone can help you.

Comment: it is simple code, I added it

Comment: please clean up your markup. id's have to be unique - you use them twice. and elements don't need a class assigned twice...

Comment: If I create different id only one button will work. I need one script for opening 2 blocks if I click on different buttons

Comment: I removed id and created classes instead but problem is the same, if I click on add-note 2 inputs appeared but should appear only 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code that have been mentioned in the comments, but I will sum then up here.

1. There are elements with the same ID. This would cause selection issues with the jQuery, as well as being something you should never do. An ID name should never be used more than once on a page with no exceptions.
2. The `.add-note` class was being added twice to the last `li` element. Although this woudn't cause an adverse effects, it isn't very good practice.
3. The jQuery was targeting two elements to be toggled, not the element that relates to the clicked button.

**Solution:**

When the click event is triggered you need to select the element that is relevant to the element that was clicked. The IDs have been switched to classes and the old `.add-node` `li` now has a class of `note`.

So inside the click event you can use `$(this)` to specify the element that has been clicked, then use `prev()` to select the `ul` next to the clicked element and then `find('.note')` to select the element to be toggled.

```js
$('.add-note').click(function() {
  $(this).prev().find('.note').toggle('slow', function() {
      // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

```html
<ul class="list-unstyled alerts-list contracts-alert-list">
  <li>
      <div class="alert-list-left">
          <div class="alert-time  contracts-alert">
              <p>10:31 AM</p>
          </div>
          <p>
              <span class="alert-title">Alert 1</span>

          </p>
      </div>
      <a href=""><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <div class="alert-list-left">
          <div class="alert-time  contracts-alert">
              <p>10:31 AM</p>
          </div>
          <p>
              <span class="alert-title">Alert 1</span>

          </p>
      </div>
      <a href=""><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <div class="alert-list-left">
          <div class="alert-time  contracts-alert">
              <p>10:31 AM</p>
          </div>
          <p>
              <span class="alert-title">Alert 1</span>

          </p>
      </div>
      <a href=""><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li class="note">
      <form action="some-action" class="add-note-form">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
          <button type="submit" class="btn form-submit-btn submit-new-note-2">Add Note</button>
      </form>
  </li>
</ul>
<button type="button" class="btn add-alert-btn add-note"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Note Here</button>


<ul class="list-unstyled alerts-list contracts-alert-list">
  <li>
      <div class="alert-list-left">
          <div class="alert-time  contracts-alert">
              <p>10:31 AM</p>
          </div>
          <p>
              <span class="alert-title">Alert 1</span>

          </p>
      </div>
      <a href=""><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <div class="alert-list-left">
          <div class="alert-time  contracts-alert">
              <p>10:31 AM</p>
          </div>
          <p>
              <span class="alert-title">Alert 1</span>

          </p>
      </div>
      <a href=""><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <div class="alert-list-left">
          <div class="alert-time  contracts-alert">
              <p>10:31 AM</p>
          </div>
          <p>
              <span class="alert-title">Alert 1</span>

          </p>
      </div>
      <a href=""><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li class="note">
      <form action="some-action" class="add-note-form">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
          <button type="submit" class="btn form-submit-btn submit-new-note-2">Add Note</button>
      </form>
  </li>
</ul>
<button type="button" class="btn add-alert-btn add-note"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Note Here</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

to only address the elements to the corresponding button, a wrapper is useful:

```
<div class="listWrapper">
  <ul class="anUnorderedList" id="firstList">
    <li>some item</li>
    <li>some other item</li>
    <li class='inputItem'>
      <form>
        <input type='text' /> <span class="saveButton">save</span></form>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="addButton">
    add another item to first list
  </div>
</div>
```

with this, you can bind a function to the button class and within the handle address the sibbling of the clicked button. i've done this, using parent->find:

```
$(".addButton").on("click", function() { 
  targetList = $(this).parent(".listWrapper").find("ul"); //find the corresponding ul

  targetList.find(".inputItem").toggle(); // toggle the li with class input item
});
```

see working fiddle, including a 'save' function: https://jsfiddle.net/x0ndL8h1/